# Sum-product algorithm in polytrees

Tags: inference, dag, belief-propagation

I want to do exact inference in a polytree structured DAG. I know that the Sum-product algorithm always converges for trees and I have also read that the algorithm can be extended for polytrees, but I am not exactly sure of what happens in this case. So my question is: does the Sum-product algorithm work for polytrees? Does it always converge?